# Using the original Intent when activity is recreated

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-lifecycle

During the activity lifecycle, when an activity is recreated besides using the `onSaveInstanceState` to save the state and restore it, we can use the values set in the extras of the original `Intent` that started the activity.
Are there any pitfalls doing this though? The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states#use_onsaveinstancestate_as_backup_to_handle_system-initiated_process_death) does not go into much detail on this

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you want to do? What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @DavidWasser: I wanted to confirm my understanding that I can always count on the original Intent and the values set in the `extras` during the complete lifecycle of my activity

Answer (score 1):

The original `Intent` is always available. When the `Activity` is recreated, `onCreate()` will always be called with the original `Intent` that launched the `Activity` and the original "extras" will always be there.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I was curious where is that explicitly stated in the official docs?

Comment: I don't know if this is explicitly written in the documentation, but that's how it works. It basically can't work any other way.